# NOT IN Clause for Multiple columns in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL query  :

```
select * from  product_structure_resources 
where resource_id NOT IN (select resource_id from resources);
```

Now I need to add the columns like branch_id and scheme_id right after the where clause .

Like :

```
select * from  product_structure_resources 
where resource_id,scheme_id,branch_id NOT IN (select resource_id from resources);
```

How can I do it ?

P.S : The resources table does not have scheme_id and branch_id column in it. It has only resource_id column .

Comment: Which databse do you use?

Comment: MySQL database on ORACLE SQL developer

Comment: So you want rows where none of `resource_id`, `scheme_id`, `branch_id` are in the subquery?

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from  product_structure_resources pr
where not exists (select 1 from resources r where pr.resource_id = r.resource_id)
and not exists (select 1 from resources r where pr.scheme_id= r.resource_id)
and not exists (select 1 from resources r where pr.branch_id= r.resource_id)
```

Comment: `select 1 from resources`, will this return column value? or just `"1"` for each row?

Comment: `1` is just a dummy value for the checking of existance.

Comment: is it fast than selecting `"*"`?

Comment: No, there is prpobably no notable difference.

Answer (score 0):

This should return the exact same result as [juergen d's query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27937428/1446005).

```
SELECT psr.*
FROM product_structure_resources AS psr
LEFT JOIN resources AS r ON r.resource_id = psr.resource_id)
LEFT JOIN resources AS s ON s.resource_id = psr.scheme_id)
LEFT JOIN resources AS b ON b.resource_id = psr.branch_id)
WHERE r.resource_id IS NULL
AND s.resource_id IS NULL
AND b.resource_id IS NULL
```

And just for fun, there also is this extreme (obscure and ill-advised) way:

```
SELECT *
FROM product_structure_resources AS psr
WHERE resource_id IN (
    SELECT resources.resource_id FROM resources
    WHERE resources.resource_id NOT IN (psr.resource_id, psr.scheme_id, psr.branch_id)
)
```

Answer (score -1):

I think it may works and helps you

```
select *
from  product_structure_resources 
where concat(resource_id,scheme_id,branch_id) NOT IN
(select concat(resource_id,scheme_id,branch_id) from resources);
```